# Legality of using Squid with --enable-ssl in production

Tags: debian, squid, openssl, licensing

Background: I am building a server application, deploying on Debian. I want to use Squid's accelerator modes to cache the resources generated by my server. Squid will most likely run on the same box as the application. Since I want to serve my resources over SSL and accept client requests over SSL, I need Squid to have its SSL support. This allows me to use the https_port directive and also communicate with the cache_peers over SSL. So the setup is that the Squid server is the SSL endpoint for my clients.

To do all this I need to build Squid with its enable-ssl flag set. I have done this internally and my setup works, and I get a good improvement in speed, so I would like to continue to use Squid. However the licenses of Squid and OpenSSL are incompatible([see here](http://www.squid-cache.org/mail-archive/squid-dev/200406/0011.html)), and this is why Debian distributes Squid without this flag set. So I am unsure as to whether or not I am allowed to redistribute or publicly host(for profit) my server. Do I need to give OpenSSL their [credit](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Licensing:FAQ?rd=Licensing/FAQ#What.27s_the_deal_with_the_OpenSSL_license.3F) on my site(I have absolutely no problem with that)? Or can I not redistribute at all?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you need. Do you want to run squid only for your company? Or do you want to redistribute the squid together with your application as an appliance? This makes a big difference.

Comment: Sorry, the plan is to redistribute as part of an appliance.

Comment: You really need a lawyer, not a system administrator. We should not and cannot give you legal advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [OpenSSL license](http://www.openssl.org/source/license.html):

> 6. Redistributions of any form whatsoever must retain the following acknowledgment: "This product includes software developed by the
>      OpenSSL Project for use in the OpenSSL Toolkit
>      (http://www.openssl.org/)"

So, you'd need to just include this in your appliance's application. If you're hosting something, you should include this somewhere in your own license/terms.